# Using CoreData to save user articles - how do I have all the articles persist in the UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I'm still new to CoreData, but I feel like I've got a good understanding of the saving and retrieval process. However, I'm confused when retrieving how we make it "seamless", like it never left (maybe it never does and I'm just not understanding).

My UITableView's model is an `NSArray` full of `Article` objects. The list is populated from the Articles.

After every new article is added, I save it to the CoreData store, so if the app crashes or what have you, I have it saved. However, how do I have it instantly be there when the user reopens it, even if it quit after being in the background?

I can fill the NSArray of Articles with the contents of core data, but that takes a bit, and then the tableview data source has to populate the tableview from it, so this would hardly be instant.

Is there a way to like make the data source for the UITableView the CoreData? Maybe I'm just really misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's quite easy actually to create a Core Data-backed TableView controller.  As a matter of fact if you create a brand new project and check the "Use Core Data" checkbox it will set it up for you automatically.

The magic comes from using an `NSFetchedResultsController` to populate the table.  Ray has a great tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller).

Basically Core Data acts as the datasource for the table view, handing it the correct record when it needs to be displayed.

See also [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451).

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [NSFetchedResultsController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It has a pretty seamless integration with Core Data.